# É possível alterar uma comparação de uma variável já existente no MatLab?

Tags: variáveis, matlab, comparação, equações

Tem como mudar/alterar a igualdade (comparação) de uma variável já existente no MatLab?.

A variável `eq` do meu programa tem como valor o primeiro destaque abaixo. Essa variável é comparada a `0`. Quero saber se tem como mudar essa comparação: em vez de ser `0`, gostaria de comparar com `1` (depois, claro, de passar `-1` do primeiro para o segundo membro da comparação).

Como é:

```
eq = A1/6 + (35*A2)/36 + (325*A3)/216 + (2375*A4)/1296 + (15625*A5)/7776 - 1 == 0
```

Como queria que ficasse:

```
eq = A1/6 + (35*A2)/36 + (325*A3)/216 + (2375*A4)/1296 + (15625*A5)/7776 == 1
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Você quem criou essa variável `eq`?

Comment: sim, fui eu. Você sabe como resolver meu problema???

Comment: Qual é exatamente seu problema? Se temos `eq=a-1==0` e `eq=a==1`, os dois produzem a mesma saida de eq como uma variável lógica, não uma variável numérica. Você deve estar usando isso para algo, coloque um pouco de contexto que pode ajudar a resolver o problema."